# How to rename and upload the files to Google drive, which are uploaded to Django admin page through FileField in models.py

Tags: python, django, upload, django-admin, rename

When a File is Uploaded to Django admin database, it gets saved into the database and the "media_url" path mentioned. I want to rename the file with the username of the user appended by timestamp and upload this renamed file to a specific folder in google drive.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: after saving to model, use may use signal or override the mode save() method to call google drive api from the the official python api [library](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). before calling the [upload api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) set the file name [metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you already have and where you're stuck.